# Response.Write("OK") gives error Object required: "" in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

What should I do to use Response.Write in VBScript?
Everything else works fine up to this statement. 
I never used VBScript before...

The code, which is my first in VBScript and is being written incrementally, works OK with exception of these objects:

```
 WScript.Echo Response.Write Print
```

I have enabled ASP but I couldn't find a way to install these objects on my PC, which acts as a development server. The production website uses VBScript, ASP and SQL Server. Here is the code:

```
'...

Do While Not Rs.EOF

AllTerms = AllTerms & Rs("Term")
Rs.MoveNext

Loop

MsgBox AllTerms

' @ Print AllTerms

' WScript.Echo AllTerms

' Response.Write Rs("Term")

Rs.Close
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I saw you tried to edit your code into @Jonco98's answer. Instead, you should edit your own question. I have done this for you now, to help you get started. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Are you using ASP? `Response` is part of the ASP object model. It's not available when running a VBScript under the Windows Script Host.

**Edit:**

I see you've updated your code and it looks like you are indeed using ASP. Since you're collecting all of the recordset info in a variable named `AllTerms`, you should be able to display it using the line:

```
Response.Write AllTerms    ' Use this in place of: MsgBox AllTerms
```

But if you're new to ASP, you may want to just create a simple page just to test your configuration. Something like this should do:

```
<%
    Response.Write "Today is " & Date
%>
```

Save it with an `.asp` extension, request the page from the web server, and make sure the output is proper.